# JenkinsFile | Declarative stage for multiple environment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a JenkinsFile declarative pipeline below is the structure-

```
pipeline{
  agent{}
    stages{
      stage(dev_one){
       steps{
        }
       }
      stage(dev_two){
       steps{
        }
       }
      stage(test_one){
       steps{
        }
       }
      stage(test_two){
       steps{
        }
       }
    }
}
```

I see there is redundancy in the JPL script, as you see stage(dev_one) and stage(test_one) will have the same steps. 
How can I reuse the stage(dev_one), so that one stage can be used for different environments.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51786981/1230748  :)

Comment: @dcalap Thank you. I have updated the code snippet. is the way I need to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the repeat code into a function, then invoke the function in multiple stages with different params.

```
pipeline{
  agent{}
    stages{
      stage(dev_one){
       steps{
          workOnEnv(this, 'dev_one', <next param>)
        }
       }
      stage(dev_two){
       steps{
          workOnEnv(this, 'dev_two', <next param>)
        }
       }
      stage(test_one){
       steps{
        }
       }
      stage(test_two){
       steps{
        }
       }
    }
}

void workOnEnv(Script script, String env, String param2, ...) {
    script.echo "work on env: $env"

    script.sh ""

    script.step()
}
```

Comment: I have added an answer. Could you reconfirm from your end

Answer (score 0):

```
void ENV_DEV_Deploy_and_Test(){
sshagent(credentials: ['iamcredentials']) {
                  sh '''
                   my script
                  '''
                }
}
    pipeline{
      agent{}
        stages{
          stage('ENV-DEV Deploy and Test') {
            steps {
               ENV_DEV_Deploy_and_Test() 
            }
        }
          stage(dev_two){
           steps{
            }
           }
          stage(test_one){
           steps{
            }
           }
          stage(test_two){
           steps{
            }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your function `ENV_DEV_Deploy_and_Test` definition looks good.  Please add arguments for it if you need it can accept parameter.